# Do I need to be a non profit to accept donations on my website?

Tags: non-profit

Suppose I have a website that run for a community. I do accept donations on it to pay for the web hosting and game servers.

Are there any requirements for a person operating such a website to apply for some kind of registration as a non profit to continue to accept these donations? If so, what?

I am not sure if it helps but I do provide ledgers of where the money goes to the public.

EDIT: I live in New York. All the servers in question are located in the US (Missouri, Seattle, New York) and one is in Montreal, Canada.

Comment: Are you able to rewrite this as a more general legal question about whether game platforms can accept donations without being non-profits?  It currently looks like a request for specific legal advice, which is off-topic.

Comment: @Ryahn where are you located and where is the server? This will help determine the relevant law.

Comment: @PatrickConheady I live in New York. The servers all (except one) reside in the US (Missouri, Seattle, and New York). The one outside of the US is in Montreal, Canada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  If you create a company that qualifies under 501(c)(3), then your donors can deduct all or part of their donations from their taxable income, but a company that doesn't qualify under 501(c)(3) can still accept donations.

Comment: Are they taxable income in the hands of the recipient?